# How do I modify the package in flutterfire?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make flutter_camera_ml_vision support null safety.
So I forked the repository of flutter_camera_ml_vision, updated the package, and ran the dart migrate command, and got the following message.

```
Before migrating your package, we recommend ensuring that every library it
imports (either directly or indirectly) has been migrated to null safety, so
that you will be able to run your unit tests in sound null checking mode.  You
are currently importing the following non-null-safe libraries:

  package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart
  package:plugin_platform_interface/plugin_platform_interface.dart
```

So I wanted to make firebase_ml_vision support null safety, so I forked the following repository of firebase_ml_vision and tried to fix it.

I tried to fork the following repository of firebase_ml_vision to fix it, but the repository of flutterfire is complicated unlike other packages, so I don't know how to fix it.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire

I understand that the changes should be reflected in the pubspec.yaml file of flutter_camera_ml_vision in the following way.

```
flutter_camera_ml_vision
　　git : ≪ my forked repository ≫
```

How do I modify it if it is configured like the flutterfire repository?

Answer (score 0):

In the recent [release note](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision/changelog), they announced the current state of the package's null-safety:

> **0.11.0** - This version is not null-safe but has been created to allow compatibility with other null-safe FlutterFire packages such as firebase_core.

Since it's not null-safe, there will be a warning, but it should be safer to use than other non null-safe package since they made necessary adjustment on the package to work with other packages.

You can follow the update timeline of the team on [this Github discussion](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/discussions/4182).